# Can an external force act on a single body in a system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Say I have a very simple example of a train, or a pulley system, or one block pulling another before they both fall of a table, so two bodies connected by a very simple mass-less cable or string.

A force will act on body A, and body B will experience a force due to the tension or pulling force from A, the forces on A are:

Force F

Tension -T from B

Forces on B:

Tension T from A.

Can I, in this scenario consider A and B to be a system? Or is this not possible due to the fact the force is not acting on both, so they cannot be a system? Would we still call this an external force acting on the system?

Answer (score 1):

The two boxes can be considered as one system just fine. It doesn't matter how you define your system - you could cherrypick specific parts to include or leave out. Your choice of system has no geometric or spatial requirements. You just must always include all influence into this system, however you then choose it.

This is often used to one's advantage, when a system is chosen carefully so that complex influences cancel out or so that symmetry and thus easier calculations are achieved. So just go ahead with your suggestion - all is good.

Comment: Would this still be an 'external force'? And would we still say 'external force acting on the system?

Comment: @user1007028 What does "this" refer to? Yes, any force acting on any part of the defined system which itself is not originating from within the system (from a part which is included in the system) is an external force. In your scenario with your chosen system, that would be for instance gravity or the mentioned pulling force.

Comment: my question is would the force be an 'external force acting on the system' as my (probably wrong) reasoning is that internal forces are within the system, and external forces act on the system as a whole, but this acts on the system, but specifically one body in the system.

Comment: @user1007028 Define a chair as your system. Gravity is an external force pulling it every particle of this chair, this system. At each leg on the floor, there is a normal force which is an external force. But it is only exerted on a tiny part of the system, namely the contact surface. So, no, external forces do not have to act on every part of the system.

Comment: I see, probably just a wrong intuition I got from studying systems of particles where usually a force acts on the system as a whole changing it's momentum etc.

Comment: @user1007028 Yes, I understand. But hopefully no such requirement of external forces acting on every bit of the system was claimed when you were introduced to the concept of systems, even though it usually is the case in idealised examples. External forces sum up to obey Newton's laws for the system as a whole regardless of which part of the system they are exerted on - the presence of such unevenly exerted external forces may have other consequences, though, such as introducing torques that might cause rotation of this system (or rearrangement/deformation of a non-rigid system).

Comment: The sum of the momentums change, e.g. the systems total momentum change, so a force acting on a part will change the total momentum of the system, and possibly its angular momentum, this is what I had wrong, to change the momentum of the 'system' is possible with just a force on a particular part, and for example there may be a change in the momentum of other parts due to reactions between particles  (such as the cable connecting my blocks) the net momentum of the system, is the sum of the momentum of each particle, I have figured this out now.